# Why does the JVM search for a method from child to parent in the inheritance tree?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Here is the example code that I am looking at and would like to know why the JVM always looks for a method in a child class when a similar method is present in the parent and when the reference is of type parent but the object is of type child.

```
class A{
    public void saveLink(){
        System.out.println("A: saveLink");
        bookmark();
    }
    public void bookmark() {
        System.out.println("A: bookmark");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public void bookmark(){
        System.out.println("B: bookmark");
    }
}

class C extends B{

}   

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A b = new B();
        A c = new C();

        c.saveLink();
    }
}
```

When I run the above code it outputs:

```
A: saveLink
B: bookmark
```

Can someone please explain more about this?

Comment: Why? Because this is how polymorphism works by definition.

Comment: Because that's the whole point of creating a child class. To extend and override the behavior of an existing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the ways in which polymorphism is implemented in Java. It's referred to as dynamic binding.

The implementation that is executed at runtime is determined by looking at the actual class of the object on which the method is called.

In your case, when you declare `A b = new B();` and then call `b.bookmark()`, Java looks first at the runtime, actual type of the object (`B` is the runtime type as the object was created with `new B()`), regardless of its static or declared type (i.e., regarless of the declared type of the variable pointing to the object).

When Java sees that the method has been overridden in the runtime class (this is the case for object `b` in your example), it executes that implementation. Otherwise, it walks up the class hierarchy to find an inherited implementation, as you've noted (this is the case for object `c` in your example).

---

Please note:

- This behavior is just for for **instance methods** (it doesn't apply to static methods or to fields). Static methods are chosen based on the declared/static type.
- There's an exception (that I can think of): when the call is done with `super.bookmark()`, then Java will necessarily run the implementation of the superclass - this is not a scenario in your example.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, because of polymorphism JVM is looking for the most specific method in the hierarchy at runtime and as per the declaration done? It do not rely on  whether the calling method and the called method are in the same class?

Comment: @mbairy No, whether there's an implementation of the invoked method in the current class doesn't matter, Java Will first look at the runtime class. Note that this is for instance methods only